# Parse.com Cloud Code and HashMaps in Android: How to set an array inside Hashmap?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parse-platform

I'm getting mad because of this. I'm using Parse.com to handle my Backend and I've to call a Cloud Code function giving this "structure":

```
{ "idShop":"asdf", "idCostumer":"zxcv", "selection": [
    {"idOffer":"product1", "quantity":3 }, 
    {"idOffer":"product2", "quantity":1 } 
] }
```

It works fine if I use curl but, I've no idea how to do it with Android. So, the idea is put an array into a JSON value.

I've tried to put all the info into a String and into a HashMap array and I got no result.

Any idea??

Thanks for helping! :)

---

After Sunil answer:

This is what I'm doing and doesn't work:

```
HashMap<String, String [] > params = new HashMap<String, String []>();
                params.put("idCostumer", new String[]{costumerId});
                params.put("idShop", new String[]{idShop});


                OfferListItem item;
                ArrayList<String> selectionList = new ArrayList<String>();

                for(int i=0; i<offerList.size();i++){                   
                    item = offerList.get(i);
                    if (item.getClicks()>0){    
                        selectionList.add("\"idOffer\":"+item.getId()+", "+"\"quantity\":"+item.getClicks());                       
                    }
                }
                String [] selection = new String [selectionList.size()];
                for (int i=0;i<selection.length;i++) {
                    selection[i]=selectionList.get(i);
                }

                params.put("selection", selection);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Parse's Android Guide](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-types), the correct data type to use for arrays is `JSONArray`. Try using `JSONArray` in place of `String []`.

Answer (score 1):

try this way, put the String array into hashmap with this way

```
 HashMap subjects = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    subjects.put("calculus",new String[] {"math","logic"});
    subjects.put("chemisty",new String[] {"ions","electrons"});
    subjects.put("biology",new String[] {"life","bacteria"});
    for(String s:subjects.get("biology")){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work it puts @[String:25161] (or similar). It puts the direction, not the object.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but try this .
In your cloud code, use use 2 array variables. The first will be for building your array objects and the second for building an 'ArrayList' so assuming you  want to return an arraylist of courses and the mark 3 students got in each you will end up with something like this.

-Cloud code

```
studentMarks={};

courses=[ ];

For(int i=0;i<3;i++)

{

studentMarks={stud1:3,stud2:10,stud3:45}

courses.push(studentMarks);

}
```

response.success(courses)

-Then in your Android code pass an ArrayList of type Object

```
public void done(ArrayList<Object> courses, ParseException e) {

// cast the course to a HashMap

HashMap<String,Object> object= (HashMap<String,Object>)courses.get(0);

int stud1 = (Integer) object.get("stud1");                      

}
```